# Calculating number of functions

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, functions

$f$ is a map defined on the set $\mathbf{F}_p$={0,1,2...p-1} to itself. The properties of $f$ are as follows:

1. $f(x)\ne x$ for all non-zero $x$ from $\mathbf{F}_p$.
2. There is exactly only one non-zero $x$ such that $f(x)=0$ and $f(0)\ne0$.

How many such map $f$ can be defined on $\mathbf{F}_p$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To satisfy condition 2, we just have to select $x\in\{1,2,...,p-1\}$ and map $x$ to $0$. This gives $p-1$ choices. $0$ can map to any nonzero element, so this also gives $p-1$ choices. The only restrictions on any other element are that it cannot map to itself or $0$, hence there are $p-2$ choices for every other element.

This gives a total of $(p-1)^2(p-2)^{p-2}$ possible maps.

Note that if you also wish to require that the mapping is surjective, then the solution is just the number of derangements of $p$.